# Splash Screen in iOS Multitasking

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, uikit

In what cases would iOS application would shows splash screen i.e., Default image (other than App Launch) ?

I am forcing a view controller to support landscape mode only

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{ 
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); 
}
```

If user is in this view and pushes the application to background and then bring it back up, app shows splash screen for < 1 second..

In another case if I have an UIAlertView open, push the application to background and bring it back up, app shows splash screen for a second.

Do we have any explanation about this in UIKit Documentation, and in what scenarios would multitasking in iOS will show user the Splash screen for a brief period.

Thanks.

**Updated Question with an example:**

If we go to Settings Application (for the first time) -> iTunes &App Stores -> Tap on AppleId: row -> You will be presented with an alertView -> Push Home button which takes the app to background -> bring the app back up. You will observe Default.png for Settings application for < 1 second before you will be presented with screen you were on before.

Comment: When saying "splash-screen" are you referring to the `Default.png` or are you referring to something you built for your app?

Comment: I am referring to Default.png

Comment: That is only displayed if the app is not running yet and is started.

Comment: @Till I have updated my question with an example. Can you please look. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system (SpringBoard) is responsible for managing your app snapshots. When you leave your app, a snapshot is written as a png file inside `Library/Caches/Snapshots/com.yourcompany.yourapp/UIApplicationAutomaticSnapshotDefault-Portrait@2x.png`

When you relaunch your app, SpringBoard tries to read that file and display it so that you have the impression that your app has woke up very fast. If it can not read that snapshot file, then it will display the `Default.png` instead.

I have noticed that `Default.png` is displayed only when you quit and relaunch your app very quickly. If you wait one or two seconds before relaunching your app, the system has time to write the snapshot and the `Default.png` is not displayed.

Since a system process is managing the display of snapshots, there is absolutely nothing you can do in your app to prevent `Default.png` to briefly appear.

Comment: Strange part is, that if a popup is currently displayed, it takes the system much longer to save the screenshot. Also in that case the screenshot is created without the alertView. Perhaps that's the reason why it takes longer. It's a big difference..

Answer (score 1):

The Default.png will only be displayed, if the app gets started from scratch. This means the first time, or it was closed completetly since it was opened the last time.

If you just run a standard app, you will see the Default.png at the first start only until it gets closed from the system (because of too less memory) or from the user via the multitasking bar.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example. Can you please look. Thanks,

Comment: Thats interesting - never observed it before! Thanks for pointing it out. Pretty strange behaviour. If you make screenshots all windows are taken into account - also the alertViews. Not only the keyWindow. Sry, but than i dont have an answer for you.

Comment: After I read 0xced answer, i just waited a little bit longer after closing the settings app with an open popup. Than it works. The app is displayed correctly (but without the popup though) while starting..